# Cakephp goes to wrong path

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am working on Cakephp. In default.ctp i give a link like

```
  <li><?= $this->Html->link('List',['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
```

I also have a ProductsController.php .

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class ProductsController extends AppController {

public function initialize(){
parent::initialize();
$this->loadcomponent('Flash');
}
public function index(){
$products = $this->Products->find('all');
$this->set(compact('products'));
}
```

But when i click on that link it give the error like

1. Error: WebrootController could not be found.
2. Error: Create the class WebrootController below in file: src/Controller/WebrootController.php

When click on toggle arguments it shows

```
object(Cake\Network\Request) {
params => [
    'plugin' => null,
    'controller' => 'Webroot',
    'action' => 'products',
    '_ext' => null,
    'pass' => [],
    '_matchedRoute' => '/:controller/:action/*',
    'isAjax' => false
]
data => []
query => []
cookies => [
    '__atuvc' => '1|21'
]
url => 'webroot/products/'
base => '/cakephp'
webroot => '/cakephp/'
here => '/cakephp/webroot/products/'
trustProxy => false
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have two .htaccess files present in your application root folder and in the webroot folder.

And make sure that an .htaccess override is allowed and that AllowOverride is set to All for the correct DocumentRoot

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#url-rewriting

Comment: Yes there are two .htaccess files are present. one is in the webroot and other is in my project folder.@Alex Stallen

Comment: and did you check if the content is the same as in the link? And make sure that an .htaccess override is allowed and that AllowOverride is set to All for the correct DocumentRoot